# Trying to count the number of the months between the dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to count number of months between two dates , But my script is throwing error

```
   var month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

   $('#test1').click(function () {

       date1_month = '29-10-2015';
       date2_month = '29-12-2015';
       var i = 0;
       while (date1_month <= date2_month) {
           var next_month = new Date(date1_month);
           next_month.setDate(date1_month.getDate() + month[date1_month.getUTCMonth()]);
           i = i + 1;
           date1_month = next_month;
       }
       $('.months').html(i);

   });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ep6nqfg/1/)

When I click on the button it is going into not ending loop I guess withouth throwing any error .

Thanks

Comment: I bet it's because `date2_month` is a string, try to convert both strings to dates before your loop. And your `new Date` doens't work, javascript has a horrrendous support for dates. You should save yourself headaches by using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by using the dates as Date instead of using string to store dates:

```
var date1_month  = new Date(2015, 10, 29); 
var date2_month  = new Date(new Date(2015, 12, 29));
var total_months = (date2_month.getFullYear() - date1_month.getFullYear())*12 + (date2_month.getMonth() - date1_month.getMonth());
alert(total_months);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b1prajwm/4/)**

Comment: actually I have another Json array which has deal so From there I am getting the deal date if that deal lies between this month then I have to show that in the respective month ,  Like this can you help me out in this http://jsfiddle.net/2ep6nqfg/5/

Answer (score 0):

The first time through your loop, your "while" statement is comparing two strings... thereafter, you are comparing an actual date with a string...

perhaps you could convert both of the initial dates to actual Date objects first (in the same way you do it inside your loop) and then compare.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ep6nqfg/3/ I fixed that problem but still its getting the same issue

Comment: @user2671011. replace your  `str`

Answer (score -1):

This is an easier way out :

```
var month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

$('#test1').click(function () {

   date1_month = '29-10-2015';
   date2_month = '29-12-2015';
   var m1 = date1_month.match(/-(.*?)-/);
   var m2 = date2_month.match(/-(.*?)-/);
   var i = Math.abs(m1[1]-m2[1]);
   $('.months').html(i);

});
```

So here are the steps taking place in the code:

1) `m1` is variable to store month from `date1` . Since month of `date1` is between two hyphens , regex is used to extract it.

2) Similarly a variable `m2` is created to store month of `date2`

4) The a variable `i` is created that stores the *positive* difference of the two months.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ep6nqfg/7/)

***NOTE:***

*I am not sure if you just want the difference between the months regardless of the year or if you want to take the difference of the year also into consideration. Please Clarify :)*

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: This only works if the two dates are in the same year.

Comment: @TarynEast Yes , I usually do that after posting the 1st edition of the answer. Working on the explanation right now :)

Comment: Why upvotes? This code doesn't work at all. The regex doesn't have surrounding /, abs is undefined (Math.abs() ?), i is NaN and so on...

Comment: @ShanShan the OP has not told anything about the difference in years

Comment: @MohitBhasi Yes but your code still doesn't work. Try logging `i`, it's a `NaN`.

Comment: @ShanShan Oh ok , I found the mistake. Check out the answer now.

Answer (score -1):

If you ever want to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/):

```
date1_month = '29-10-2015';
date2_month = '29-12-2015';
date1 = moment(date1_month, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
date2 = moment(date2_month, 'DD-MM-YYYY');

var diffMonths = Math.abs(date1.diff(date2, 'months'));
```

Comment: can you tell me how I can do that if I have to check in a date lies between that date , something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2ep6nqfg/5/

Comment: You can compare two dates just like you did but make sure you don't compare to strings or you'll get weird result. Again, with momentjs, there is an [helper](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/).